# Big C# source file with Windows API method signatures, structures, constants: will they all be included in the final .exe?

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, pinvoke, external

I want to put all the signatures of Windows API functions I'm using in programs in one class, such as WinAPI, and in a file WinAPI.cs I will include in my projects. The class will be *internal static* and the methods *public static extern*. (Something like the huge NativeMethods.cs from the .NET Framework source code).

Let's say WinAPI.cs has one hundred native methods signatures like:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

1. If I'm only going to use a few of them in a project (even one or two), if I include the WinAPI.cs file in my project, will the final .exe be filled with the unnecessary method declarations I'm not using (the other 99 or so)?
2. What about native structure declarations, If I'm not using them in the current project, will they still be included in the final .exe?

   ```
       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
       public struct POINT
       {
           public int X;
           public int Y;
       }
   ```
3. What about constants declarations or readonly members like:

   ```
   public const int WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1;
   public static readonly int WM_GETTEXT = 0x0D;
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* of this will be included.  However, it will be included as IL and when the program runs it's just compiled machine code.  We're talking maybe 40K of space at most.

Comment: Do you know why are them all included? It's an internal class, so it shouldn't be referenced from outside. Why isn't the C# compiler be able to see the unused declarations and simply remove them?

Comment: @David Because you don't know at compile time whether they'll be used or not.  Any assembly (including .exe files) might need to be referenced by another project, and you don't know about that when you compile the project.

Comment: Even if it's an internal class? "Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly"?

Comment: @David - If they are internal and not required by a public item in the assembly somewhere, you may as well just delete them.

Comment: The whole idea is to reuse the WinAPI.cs between projects. Methods not used in the current project may be used by another project, so I just can't simply delete them.

Comment: @David - again, the compiler doesn't know this.  It doesn't know that you're sharing the same file among several projects (a bad idea, by the way: put this in it's own assembly).  It expects that anything marked internal is ultimately used by something that's public.

Answer (score 4):

Don't sweat the small stuff here.  These are just declarations, there is no IL for them in the final assembly.  They just take up some space in the metadata.  Odds are very high that they don't even get loaded from the assembly, especially when you keep the declarations together.  Metadata is only ever loaded into RAM when it is used, 4096 bytes at a time.

Btw, you explicitly don't want to use *readonly* for these constant declarations.  Now you *do* get them to take space, even when they are not used.  One of the few cases where a public const is a good idea.  These are manifest constants, their value never changes.  Like Math.PI.

Answer (score 2):

All elements which you have stated will be included in final assembly.
The only way to get rid of them from final exe file is precompilation directives usage.
For example:

> ```
> #if EXCLUDE_METHODS
> ```
>
> //unused methods here
>
> ```
> #endif
> ```

Comment: "The scope of a symbol created with #define is the file in which it was defined." This means I cannot define EXCLUDE_METHODS in my project C# source files, I must do it in the WinAPI.cs file, that makes reusing this file impossible.

Comment: You can do it by editing properties of your *.csproj file. Properties->Build->Conditional compilation symbols. There define EXCLUDE_METHODS and this symbol will have assembly scope.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm only going to use a few of them
>   in a project (even one or two), if I
>   include the WinAPI.cs file in my
>   project, will the final .exe be filled
>   with the unnecessary method
>   declarations I'm not using (the other
>   99 or so)?

Yes, all code in your project will be compiled into your assembly;

> What about native structure
>   declarations, If I'm not using them in
>   the current project, will they still
>   be included in the final .exe?

Yes. They will be included too.

> ```
>    What about constants declarations or readonly members like:
> ```

Yes. They will be included too.

Comment: Doesn't the C# compiler know how to optimize that? Why include them if they are not used?

Comment: David - what if you went and referenced your assembly to use it as a library and the constant wasn't there?

Comment: It's an internal class, isn't it supposed to be accessible only within files in the same assembly?

Comment: @David, there are means to expose `internal` classes to the outside world, such as the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute...

Comment: @David, I say even more. If you would have a private class and/or private methods they all are available through Reflection. So compiling them is necessary for such a functionality.